# How to show maven-surefire-plugin unit test coverage report on console

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, maven-surefire-plugin, test-coverage

I want to show unit test coverage report in tabular format whenever someone executes `mvn test` on console itself. I found that `maven-surefire-plugin` can only produce report in XML or HTML format and even that to a directory (`target/coverage-report`). Is there some other plugin that can help me achieve same output?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can set the [`useFile`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#useFile) attribute to `false`:

> Option to generate a file test report or just output the test report to the console.

By default, this attribute is `true` which means that `maven-surefire-plugin` will output the reports to files and not in the console.

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.19.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <useFile>false</useFile>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: is it working? I don't see any results in console//